# ArrayList with unlimited predefined values

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, data-structures

I would like to know how to initialize an ArrayList which has an unlimited amount of predefined values, so I could access an element of an arbitrary index and update its value.

For example, the ArrayList `testArrayList` would be initiated with all `int` value `0`, I could immediately use `testArrayList.set(123, 15)` to set the 124th element in the ArrayList to `15` instead of getting an out of bound exception. When I do queries like `testArrayList.get(99999)`, I would get the predefined value `0`.

I've been trying to initialize an ArrayList first then use a for loop to add `0`s to it, but I have to decide how big the initial ArrayList should be. If I made a ArrayList then immediately add 100 `0`s to it, I couldn't do a `.get(200)` on it before adding another amount of `0`s.

Is what I'm looking for possible with ArrayList? If not, would you recommend some alternative solutions?

Thank you.

Edit: The reason I wanted a List is that I wanted to be able to iterate through it in order. I'm making a simple calendar-like program, where I could add/retrieve/modify "notes" of an arbitrary "date", but also able to print out the notes of every "day" given a specific period.

Comment: Maybe you can describe the problem you are trying to solve which prompted you to ask this question.

Comment: Why do you need a list with unlimited predefined values?

Comment: Implement your own ArrayList, and add your requirement to the methods

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the post to include a problem description.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and try something, and then we can help with that?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to create an `ArrayList`, since in order to populate the `99999`'th index, you'll have to populate indices `0` to `99998` first, which is wasteful.

A `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` is a better option, since you only populate the indices you care about.

A `HashMap` with an `Integer` key can be thought of as if you are mapping the indices of your "sparse ArrayList" into a small array, which reduces storage requirements while keeping the expected insertion and lookup times constant.

For example:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
int value = map.getOrDefault(99999,0); // this will return 0 if the Map has no value 
                                       // for the key 99999
map.put (99999, value + 1);
```

EDIT: seeing your requirement for iteration order, you can use `TreeMap<Integer,Integer>` instead of `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`. This way iterating over the keys will always be according to their numeric order.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a try with TreeMap.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like an `ArrayList` (or any kind of `List`) is really want you want. It sounds like you want a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

But if you want it as an `ArrayList`, you could subclass it and override `get` and `set` such that they check whether the list is large enough for the index and, if not, fill it to the point where it is.

Loosely, for `set`:

```
@Override
public E set(int index, E element) {
    if (this.size() <= index) {
        this.ensureCapacity(index + 1);
        for (int n = this.size(); n <= index; ++n) {
             this.set(n, 0);
        }
    }
    return super.set(index, element);
}
```

**But**, again, it seems like a `Map` might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to fill a sparsely populated array on the fly.

To my knowledge, there is no such thing in the Java built-in libraries.

Option space:

- use another data structure, that is more suited for "sparse" content. What is the point of having 123 empty slots? When you have just a slots with real content ... a Map might better fit your needs.
- you can always implement your own version of List which "creates" all those empty slots on demand

Answer (score 0):

Hide the access to the list behind a custom method. Fetch the index defensively, if the list does not have enough items, add default items to the list until it reaches the desired index. If the next index is less or equal the size, get that index. Else repeat.

There is no default-structure with unlimited default values (it would not be very efficient). By hiding the list as described above you only have as many items as you need (or as you think you need).